# Locally setting up redirect to https://

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, hosts

I have read a few answers to try and find a solution to a ridiculous problem.

I dont have access to a server that I can log on to access phpmyadmin,

What is supposed to happen is that the web url is supposed to be viewed via https, and in most cases this happens.

Except for a particular PC I have at home and it never seems to open in https.  Why this is happening on this given machine is completely unknown.

Is there a way I can set up a rule on my local machine that will ALWAYS convert http://pathtomysite.com to https://pathtomysecuresite.com, (possibly via the 'hosts' entry (and yes it is a windows machine running win10).

I could do this on the web server itself, I know how to do this, but the problem is, I don't have, nor am I allowed to have, access to the database server to update the .htaccess or webconfig.xml on the server. (I am 99% sure its Apache, not nginx or IIS).

Any help is allows gratefully received.